# J2ME Bluetooth - discover a service with unknown details

Tags: java-me, bluetooth

Lets say I have a device which my cell phone can connect to via bluetooth (it can be any device on the market...)

For being able to connect this device using a J2ME application on my cell phone, I need to discover the device first, and then discover the service which the device lets cell phones connect to.

My problem is that I don't know how to discover that service.... the device is being discovered with no problems by the J2ME application, but for discovering the service of this device, I need service's UUID and Attributes (J2ME API requirements), which I have no idea where and how to get.

Does anyone know how can I still connect the device's service using a J2ME application, without knowing service's UUID and Attributes ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there is nothing in the API to directly do "remote service discovery", but I found [this](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-6171367.html), which I think is about that:

> Service discovery allows you to find
>   nearby services, regardless of what
>   devices are offering them.
>   DiscoveryAgent provides methods to
>   discover services on a Bluetooth
>   server device and to initiate
>   service-discovery transactions. Before
>   a service can be discovered, it must
>   first be registered or advertised on a
>   Bluetooth server device. The server is
>   responsible for a number of things,
>   including creating a service record
>   that describes the service offered,
>   accepting connections from clients,
>   and adding a service record to the
>   server's Service Discovery Database
>   (SDDB). In general, it works like Web
>   services.